# mod_rewrite REQUEST_FILENAME change after rule without L flag

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a `.htaccess` file and have come across some curious behavior with `REQUEST_FILENAME` that I'd love some clarification about. I have two rules I'm testing out which are like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/index.php$ /other_page.php [L]
```

When I try to go to the address `site.com/this_file_exists.php` I seem to be getting to `other_page.php`, which means that
`REQUEST_FILENAME` was a file in the first RewriteCond but not a file
by the time `mod_rewrite` processed the second RewriteCond.

After changing the second RewriteRule's flags to `[L,E=RF:%{REQUEST_FILENAME}]`, and `echo`ing `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_RF']` on `other_page.php`, I find that the request filename was just `/index.php`, as opposed to the original filename, which was `/full/path/to/this_file_exists.php`.

Does `mod_rewrite` consistently overwrite the `REQUEST_FILENAME` in this way after matching a RewriteRule? If so, is there a documented way in which it does that?

Answer (score 0):

These lines in `mod_rewrite.c`

```
/* Now adjust API's knowledge about r->filename and r->args */
r->filename = newuri;
```

seem to suggest that the new REQUEST_FILENAME truly is
the rewritten URI.

Comment: Try checking [the docs here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), there is a section talking about `REQUEST_FILENAME` in that section.